# Check if a preload function is working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, preload

I found somewhere this function for preloading images from a folder.
How can I check if it's working correctly?

Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var folder = "//static.thisisfed.com/img/";
  $.ajax({
    url: folder,
    success: function(data) {
      $(data).find("a").attr("href", function(i, val) {
        if(val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/)) {
          $("body").append("<img src='" + folder + val + "'>");
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: if //static.thisisfed.com/img/ is a html page with links to the images this will work

Comment: What do you mean by _preloading images from a folder_?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
var myImage = new Image(100, 200);
myImage.src = 'picture.jpg';
myImage.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector('div').appendChild(myImage)
}
```

use this to **preload img** in JavaScript.

Comment: you can use `var myImage = document.createElement('img')` too.